# Testing Async Function With Progress Object in Jasmine / Karma With AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, jasmine

I have a third party library function bound to an Angular `$scope` variable in my application.  The function is used in the following manner in my app:

```
        var request = $scope.libraryObject.upload(someParams, function(){
            $scope.testValue= false;
            $scope.$apply();
        });

        request.on('httpUploadProgress', function(data){
            $("#someElement").attr({
                value: data.loaded,
                max: data.total
            });
        });
```

The function returns two things: an object used to dynamically update the current progress of the upload and a callback function which is executed on completion of the upload.  In my Jasmine test suite, I currently have

```
        spyOn(scope.libraryObject, 'upload').and.returnValue({
            on: function(firstParam, secondParam){}
        });
```

which allows me to successfully mock the `request.on()` method.

How would I add to this so that I can also test the callback function associated with `$scope.libraryObject.upload()` - specifically that `$scope.testValue` is correctly set to false?